# Keep __EVENTVALIDATION server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate, eventvalidation

I'm trying to keep the pagesize of an ASP.NET webforms application as small as possible.

One of the steps was keeping the hidden field values for __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION server side.

Keeping __VIEWSTATE serverside was simple enough by overriding the PageStatePersister method of the Page object and returning my own implementation.

However, I can't seem to find a means to do this with the __EVENTVALIDATION field. As it's the same idea, a base64 encoded value in a hidden field, I would have expected to the be able to perform a similar task to the viewstate method.

Can anyone advise how I would go about it?